# docker multiply hostnames for one container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can i add multiply hostnames for some docker in docker-compose? Container should see by self many hostnames, for example:

```
ping name: should resolve 127.0.0.1 (or $docker_ip)
ping another.name: should resolve 127.0.0.1 (or $docker_ip)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extra-hosts](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/extrahosts):

```
extra_hosts:
 - "name:127.0.0.1"
 - "another.name:127.0.0.1"
```

Has the same effect as `docker run --add-host`:

```
> docker run --add-host another.name:127.0.0.1 sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils ping another.name
PING another.name (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
```